# Exit from while loop after catching signal

Tags: bash, while-loop, signals

I'm writing a bash script to capture a signal from another program:

```
trap "echo Signal" SIGUSR1 
while :         
do
        sleep 1 
done
COMMAND 1
COMMAND 2
COMMAND 3
.........
```

I want to exit from the while loop after catching the signal, in order to launch COMMAND 1,2,3 and so on.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your commands in a function and then use the function in your trap:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'trp' SIGUSR1
trp() {
        COMMAND 1
        COMMAND 2
        COMMAND 3
        ......... 
}
while :         
do
    sleep 1        
done
```

Comment: Can you select the response as the answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable

```
finished=0
trap 'finished=1;echo Signal' SIGUSR1
while ! ((finished))
do
    sleep 5
    echo sleeping
done
echo done
```